# Using VS 2013 with an activation key after BizSpark graduation?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, bizspark

If Visual Studio 2013 was activated using a **static activation key** obtained through BizSpark in **2014**, will it still **work after graduation** date in 2017?

Never signed in to VS. Product Information says "*License Product key applied*".

I remember seeing an email from Microsoft somewhere in 2015 that said something  like:
*"If you have saved your product key before [some_date_in_2015] you will be able to continue using Visual Studio 2013 after you graduate."*

**Does that still apply?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simply - **YES**.
Confirmed first hand. It still works like it worked since the day one.

The important thing is that Visual Studio 2013 was activated using a static activation key obtained through BizSpark **and activated** before Microsoft changed the activation policy to login-only (around mid 2015).

There is a **slight** possibility that it is still possible to install VS V2013 using the **old ISO** installation image and activate it using a static key.